# How to resolve the following error in discord.py: "TypeError BotBase.__init__() missing one keyword-only argument: 'intents'"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am using the following code to run my discord bot:

```py
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
```

However, when trying to run it in vscode, I get the following error:

```py
Exception has occurred: TypeError BotBase.__init__() missing one keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

What does this error mean, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: A couple of things, 

1. Please add the code so we can understand the context

2. When naming a function or a part of the code use 2 backticks (`)

3. As written in the exception,  you probably forgot to pass all of the required arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Intents is a change done by the Discord API. You need to subscribe to these in order to get access to some gateway events. You can do:

```py
intents=discord.Intents.default()
```

to make your bot subscribe to basic intents. More information on intents: [click here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html).